# How much does each cartridge of Spider-Man's web shooters weigh?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Given the fact that he can shoot a ridiculous amount of webbing from each cartridge, they have to be quite dense and must have a substantial amount of weight. Given Spider-Man's strength, we can assume that he can carry a few cartridges without much difficulty and also fight with a cartridge on each of his wrists without much setback. Has it ever been mentioned in any comics or anywhere else how much each of his cartridges weigh?

Comment: I'm not sure your premise is sound: one of the key "selling points" of spider silk is how strong it is *while still being lightweight*. Any artificial fluid trying to mimic it would likely have the same properties?

Comment: He can also stop a train.   I don't think this question is constructive.

Comment: I've got my [best people](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/is-this-pressure-vessel-feasible) working on it for you.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I don't see how this is attracting downvotes. Spiderman carries multiple cartridges. If the weight is non-trivial, that's quite interesting.

Comment: if his max train stopping power naked is a 10 ton train 25 pounds, and 2 ounces, and he has a couple pounds of spider silk on him, and the train he needs to stop is exactly 10 ton 25 pounds and 2 ounces, hes gana die, need this weight for science.

Comment: @Mike - If the webs are too light, it will not be possible for Spider-Man to shoot his webs to the amount of distance he usually does due to air friction and he will also lose accuracy.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say it's already "not possible" for him to use the fluid the way he does, so air resistance is probably the least of his problems.

Comment: If it helps, MJ had some spider-shooters (with a considerably weakened trigger so that she could use it without super-strength) given to her by Peter while she was a model, so the cartridges are not that heavy.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - Re: Your first comment; I'm not sure that follows.  The SILK that is produced would have to mimic the properties of spider silk, but the non-silk form might not.  Think of Sugar -> Cotton Candy.  In compressed form, it might have significant weight, especially if the 'spinning' process fillings it largely with air.  True, this would tend to imply the charges should produce quite a lot per cartridge, but they've always been driven by '[needs of plot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot)' anyway, as to their capacity.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://marvel.com/universe/Spider-Man's_Web-Shooters) on the Marvel.com website, we can begin to rough out some numbers.

**Dimensions:** Based on a rough eyeball assessment, I'm assuming the cartridges are somewhere around 60mm x 60mm x 15mm in height, length and depth in order to fit into Spider Man's web-shooter without sticking out.

---

**Materials:** We know that the body of the cartridge is...

> **mainly** [made from] **nickel-plated annealed brass ... and sealed with a bronze cap which is silver soldered closed.**

For ease of calculation, we'll assume that the whole cartridge is made of brass.

---

**Weight:** Given these constraints, **the upper weight of the cartridge cannot be higher than 1 pound (0.45Kg)**. The cartridge also has a hollow chamber (containing the spider-string) which means that the overall weight must be slightly lower, possibly by as much as 75%.

---

Spiderman has a belt which contains approximately 20 of these cartridges (along with a hidden camera) which means that he's carrying approximately 20 pounds of weight (9kg) around with him. Although this may seem a non-trivial amount for you or I, since Spider Man possesses [superhuman strength](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Strength_Scale) this weight may barely register with him.

[image]