# Does Spider-Man ever save his empty web cartridges?

Tags: marvel, technology, spider-man

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*

> at the beginning of his fight with Vulture on the boat

he discharges his empty web canisters and reloads them. When they pop out he doesn't bother picking them up (litter bug!). I don't know how easy/expensive they are to make, but they don't [weigh](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103781/75000) very much, and given their size they don't take up a lot of space, so it would seem to behoove him to recycle if nothing else than to save time making more.

**So does Spider-Man ever save/collect his web cartridges after they're spent?**

Note that I am not asking about Homecoming or the MCU specifically. The movie is only an example.

Comment: I seem to remember scenes (from the comics) where he's had to swap out an empty cartridges for a full one. And, certainly, there have been times where maintaining his supplies for his webbing has stretched his budget. So, I'd think that re-filling an empty cartridge, (if possible), would have occurred to him at some point. That said, one suspects that the cartridges are the cheapest part of the web fluid; the necessary chemicals are probably more expensive.

Comment: @RDFozz Could you find any comics that talk about Peter's financial struggles regarding his superhero costs? Something we can at least infer from?

Comment: Well, since Dan Slott put Peter to work at Horizon, he's been pretty solvent. However, historically, he's frequently lived pretty much hand to mouth. There are numerous references form the first 10 years or so to needing to get money to get Aunt May's medicine, pay his rent, etc. I vaguely recall a time or two where he had money issues with keeping his costume in repair, and (in the back of my mind) I'm almost certain there was a reference to issues cooking up a new batch of web fluid. However, having read most of the Spider-Man stories from the past 50+ years, I can't recall a specific issue.

Comment: @RDFozz Dang. Well, it sounds like you might be on to something there. It might need some connections made and some speculation built, but it might be the best we got, and I would happily upvote it. :)

Answer (score 9):

Spider-Man has a utility belt with spare web cartridges

> [image: Spider-Mans utility belt containing spare web cartridges]

There also is a panel where he mentions that all his web cartridges in his belt are empty

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #230](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_230)</sup></sub>

So yes, he does in fact put them back into his utility belt after they are empty. Which only makes sense, considering Peter's often limited funds. He cannot afford to leave them around and not fill them back up.

Comment: What comics are these from?

Comment: The last one is from The Amazing Spider-Man #230. The first one I can't say. It's an example image of his belt I found on comic vine, sadly without a reference to where it came from.